# Click on a theme in a forum

Tags: php

I have a table named ***forums*** with 4 fields: id_forum, title, theme, fk_user.

[image]

When, I am on my page **view_forum** and that I click on a theme for example *PHP*, I get all the messages of all themes on the page **view_message**.

[image]

I don't understand how to recuperate only the messages of the theme PHP.

Because, the theme Python should not be displayed.

My table ***messages*** has 5 fields: id_message, contents, date_message, fk_user, fk_forum.

In my file **view_forum**, the request is below:

```
$requestSQL = "SELECT forums.*, users.pseudo 
               FROM forums INNER JOIN users
               ON forums.fk_user=users.id_user 
               ORDER BY id_forum ASC";
```

In overview

```
while($row = $stm->fetch()){ ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row ['id_forum'];?></td> 
  <td><?php echo $row ['title'];?></td> 
  <td><a href="view_message"><?php echo $row ['theme'];?></a></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['pseudo'];?></td>
</tr>
```

My problem is perhaps in this line?

```
 <td><a href="view_message"><?php echo $row ['theme'];?></a></td>
```

In my **view_message** my request is:

```
SELECT messages.*, users.pseudo , forums.* 
FROM messages messages INNER JOIN users users
ON messages.fk_user=users.id_user INNER JOIN forums forums 
ON messages.fk_forum = forums.id_forum ORDER BY id_message ASC
```

in overview

```
while($resultat = $stm->fetch()){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $resultat['id_message'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $resultat['contents'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $resultat['date_message'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $resultat['pseudo'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $resultat['theme'];?></td>
  </tr>
```

Thank you for your help because I am really stuck.

Comment: Where is your `WHERE` keyword in your query which would filter the `SELECT` query by a condition (like "only messages of a given theme")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change

```
    <td><a href="view_message"><?php echo $row ['theme'];?></a></td>
```

To

```
    <td><a href="view_messagesearch?themeid=id"><?php echo $row ['theme'];?></a></td>
```

Then use the GET variable in the view_message page to retrieve unique records.